# Python Dataframe column matching

Tags: python, pandas, text, tags

I have 2 columns A & B. A contains text values separated by '_' and B has some description related to A.

Example:

```
*Col         Terms
AB_BCN_PRC   About Bitcoin Price
AC_CR_STT    Account credit Statement
A6_AT_MD     Audi Automatic Model*
```

I need to map A and B so in future if a new value comes in A it should frame B automatically

Example:

```
*A         B
AB_CR_STT  About credit Statement*
```

Any idea or possible ways to get this done?

Comment: do you mean you want to autogenerate a description for given A column syntax word? like some sort of an application of some wize modeling?

Answer (score 0):

If you can define a good complete mapping dictionary (each name separated by _ as a key, the text represented by this name as a value), it can be easily implemented, and finally I used pandas to combine into the format in your example, you can also use print directly, the main focus on the function gen_terms, by the name you provide to return the full text, you can expand on this basis according to the functions you need(Make sure that each item in the name you pass in, separated by _, is the one you defined in the col_map)：

```
import pandas as pd

def gen_terms(col):
    col_map = {
        "AB": "About",
        "BCN": "Bitcoin",
        "PRC": "Price",
        "AC": "Account",
        "CR": "credit",
        "STT": "Statement",
        "A6": "Audi",
        "AT": "Automatic",
        "MD": "Model",
    }
    spans = col.split("_")
    return " ".join([col_map.get(data) for data in spans])


name = "AB_CR_STT"

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["AB_CR_STT"], "B": [gen_terms("AB_CR_STT")]})

print(df)

#            A                       B
# 0  AB_CR_STT  About credit Statement
```